# Typescript how to combine two lambda expressions

Tags: lambda, typescript

How to combine two lambda expressions with Typescript,

C# does have class Expression-Func to work with lambda expressions but Typescript does not have this option.

I have one function that pass lambda expression to func called GetCurrentRange

for example`this.GetCurrentRange(start, end, x => x.AccountId== Account.id)`

and the other function add on it expression.

`result = result.And(x => x.Date >= CurrentStart);`

How can i do this with Typescript,

sure here more details

Edit here

```
private GetCurrentRange(start?: Date, end?: Date, activeSpec: (exception: AccountTransaction) => boolean)
    {
        var result = activeSpec;
       /// some code here

       result = result (need to add exception here )(x => x.Date >= currentStart);  

    }
}
return result;
```

}

```
public Update(_account: Account, start?: Date, end?: Date): void
{  // some code here 
var transactions = Query(this.GetCurrentRange(start, end, x => x.AccountId == _account.id)); }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question fully, can you show a more complete example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the question... here is a full example, after which a quick explanation:

```
class Example {
    constructor(
        public num: number,
        public bool: boolean
    ) {}
}

var examples: Example[] = [
    new Example(5, true),
    new Example(5, false),
    new Example(6, true),
];

function exampleFilter(arr: Example[], predicate: (x: Example) => boolean) {
    var matches: Example[] = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (predicate(arr[i])) {
            matches.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return matches;
}


function exampleFilter2(arr: Example[], predicate: (x: Example) => boolean) {

    var newPredicate = function(x: Example) {
        return x.bool && predicate(x);
    }

    var matches: Example[] = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (newPredicate(arr[i])) {
            matches.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return matches;
}

var a = exampleFilter(examples, (x) => x.num < 6);
console.log(a);

var b = exampleFilter2(examples, (x) => x.num < 6);
console.log(b);
```

So the difference between `exampleFilter` and `exampleFilter2` is the extension of the predicate, which is done like this:

```
var newPredicate = function(x: Example) {
    return x.bool && predicate(x);
}
```

So this is the technique you can employ to make a refinable item as you describe in your question.

## Query Class

Here is a basic example of a class that will act as a generic query over an array of type T.

```
class Query<T> {

    constructor(private arr: T[], private predicate: (x:T) => boolean) {}

    and(predicate: (x:T) => boolean) {
        var priorCondition = this.predicate;
        this.predicate = (x:T) => {
            return priorCondition(x) && predicate(x);
        }
        return this;
    }

    toList() {
        var matches: T[] = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++) {
            if (this.predicate(this.arr[i])) {
                matches.push(this.arr[i]);
            }
        }
        return matches;
    }
}
```

The `and` method simply merges each predicate it is passed.

```
var q = new Query(examples,  (x) => x.num < 6);
q.and((x) => x.bool);

var result = q.toList();
```

Or even:

```
var result = new Query(examples,  (x) => x.num < 6).and((x) => x.bool).toList();
```

## Caution

Beware of one mistake I have seen a few times in this zone... we have an API now that looks a bit like Linq and acts a bit like Linq - but you'll need to use [ECMAScript 6 generators if you want to actually work like Linq](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2014/03/real-linq-style-operations-using-ecmascript-6/).